# How can I link to Google Sheet from Google Form? (Exploring Make a Copy feature, but I need it to be shared with the original owner)

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, google-forms, user-permissions

I'm posting here because I'm hoping someone can help me edit the link to a google sheet. I haven't been able to find the answer online, but I'm hoping maybe someone understands how the link works better than I and can give me an answer.

I've been tasked with updating the application for funding (from a non-profit) to include a budget category. The application is in Google Forms, but there's no way to insert a table into the form for an applicant to fill out. I created the budget outline in a Google Sheet, but now I'm trying to find the best solution to create an individual link within the form that will lead them to the budget document. Essentially, I'm hoping the applicant can fill out the form, and when they reach the section about their budget, I want them to click the link to the google sheet, have it make a copy, but have the copy be shared with the organization's google account so we can see it when they submit their application.

I've experiment with the forced copy feature (editing the shared link by google), but when I test it from a different google account than the owner, it tells me I have to request permission. The share settings are set to allow anyone with the link to access, so I don't understand why it's asking me to request permission when I open the force copy link. This isn't going to work because the applicants need to access it when applying, and we can't have them waiting for us to accept the request every time.

I'm sure there could be a few solutions, so I'm open to any advice. The only other solution I can possibly think of is creating individual links for each applicant, if there's a way to automate that?

I recognize there could be a solution where I ask the applicant to download the file and re-upload, or share it themselves, but our applicants are not native english speakers and they are often non very comfortable with technology, so I want to automate the process as much as possible.

To summarize: The applicant should be able to

1. Fill out the google form
2. Receive an individual copy of the budget document (from google sheets) to fill out.
3. The budget document must be shared with the original owner so we can see it and see how it relates to the rest of their application.

Thank you for your consideration!

Answer (score 0):

#### A solution for your use-case would be to make use of Apps Script.

Apps Script is a powerful development platform which can be used to build web apps and automate tasks. What makes it special is the fact that it is easy to use and to create applications that integrate with G Suite.

Taking this into account, you can create a script which will create a copy of the document whenever a new form submission is made and add the permissions needed *for the user*. Essentially, you will be the one owning the copy of the sheet as well and the candidates will have edit permissions.

Therefore, the script will end up looking something similar to this:

#### Code

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  let sheetId = 'ORIGINAL_SPREADSHEET_ID';
  let form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  let responses = form.getResponses();
  let n = responses.length;
  let currentUser = form.getResponse(responses[n-1].getId()).getRespondentEmail();
  let newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).copy("Sheet copy for " + currentUser);
  let newSpreadsheetId = newSpreadsheet.getId();
  DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheetId).addEditor(currentUser);
}
```

#### Explanation

The above snippet makes use of the Apps Script's `onFormSubmit` installable trigger. Basically, whenever a new form submission is sent, the code above will run. The code will retrieve the last response which was submitted and get the user's email address by making use of the `getRespondentEmail` method. Afterwards, a copy of the original spreadsheet will get created and shared with the **editor** permission with the user who just submitted the form. Adding the permission is done by making use of the `addEditor` method from the `DriveApp` parent class. As for the user accessing the copy of the spreadsheet, this is easily done as the user will end up receiving an email telling them that a spreadsheet has been shared with them.

#### Setup

1. You will have to have the **Collect emails** option checked for the form;

[image: form collect emails option]

2. Open the three dots icon and click on **Script Editor**;

[image: form script editor]

3. Once you open the script editor, input the code from above and do not forget to modify the `sheetId` such that it matches the id of your original spreadsheet that you want to share.
4. Install the `onFormSubmit` trigger by going to the **Triggers** page and create a new trigger with the following options:

[image: onformsubmit trigger]

5. Send the URL form to the candidates and wait for submission to be sent.

#### Reference

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script);
- [Apps Script Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [Apps Script SpreadsheetApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app);
- [Apps Script FormApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app);
- [Apps Script DriveApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app).